# Ember.js: How can I decouple my views from my controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

I'm trying to restructure tightly coupled portions of an ember.js app, particularly views and templates to controllers.

All the examples I've seen bind views directly to controllers in the view's class definition, or by pass the (global) controller path to the view in the template itself.

The TargetActionSupport mixin (DelegateSupport in sproutcore, I think) seems like a good candidate, but would still require the target (controller) and action to be set in the template itself.

Ideally, I would like to instantiate my views in my controller (somehow), set targets and actions, but *also* set presentational variables in my templates (ex: static classes, id), but I'm not sure how to accomplish something this, or whether it's the right approach.

Comment: The argument for MVC is clear. The controller adds a defined set of operations that can be done on the model. Anyone who's been around a largish project where say JSP pages make changes directly to the data know why. In my view that's enough abstraction (considering that ever bit of abstraction comes at a cost). What's the purpose of going one more step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can programmatically instantiate views and insert them into the DOM wherever you'd like:

```
var view = Ember.View.create();
view.appendTo('#someElement');
```

If you want to eliminate global binding paths, you can pass in a controller reference to the view on instantiation:

```
var controller = Ember.Object.create({content: {}}),
    view = Ember.View.create({
      controller: controller,
      contentBinding: 'controller.content'
    });
```

I'd also suggest looking into the Ember StateManager.